# How to embed a form multiple times in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, embed

I have 2 entities: Tarifa and TarifaPeso (this one has to appear 20 times in the Tarifa form).

The relation in Tarifa is:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TarifaPeso", mappedBy="tarifa", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $pesos;
```

I have embed the form as Symfony2 doc says and everything is ok, but I do not want to do it dinamically, it has to appear just 20 times. So Tarifa is a form and has to have 20 TarifaPeso form embeded.

Do you know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Instead of using entity class "Tarifa" as an underlying data class for the form, you make another two classes, say "[your bundle]/Form/Model/Tarifa" and "[your bundle]/Form/Model/TarifaPeso". Then you add 20 instances of TarifaPeso to Tarifa and display the form. When the form is submitted, pick all data from the Tarifa, instantiate and store your entities. Make a service for that, don't do it in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've done this in the constructor of the parent form class (in the entity):

```
    $this->envios = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count(self::$KILOS); $i++) {
        $peso = new TarifaPeso();
        $peso->setKilosMaxlim(self::$KILOS[$i]);
        $this->addPeso($peso);
    }
```

having $KILOS:

```
private static $KILOS = array(1,2,3,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,300,500,1000,1001);
```

In this way I modify the form with an eventListener in this way:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('precio', null, array(
            'attr' => array('autofocus' => true),
            'label' => 'label.precio ' ,
        ));
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        if ($data) {
            $valor = $data->getKilosMaxlim();

            $field = $form->get('precio');
            $config = $field->getConfig();
            $options = $config->getOptions();
            $options['label'] = 'Valor para '.$valor; // change the label
            $form->add($field->getName(), $config->getType()->getName(), $options);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have maintaining a `@ORM\OneToMany` association, [Collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) should solve your purpose. You just have to associate 20 instances of `TarifaPeso` with `Tarifa` Entity before generating the form.

[See here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) how to embed the collection form type.

Make sure you have `cascade-persist` enabled from `Tarifa` Entity for automatically `insert` or `update` `TarifaPeso` entities.

From my experience with `Collection` field types. This will be faster and easier in terms of data integrity.